# Fetch data from live database using json_encode

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to the StackExchanges so be a little soft on me. :)

So I want to ask about MySql and PHP.
I have a table named `sdat14040` that contains column `hash` and `l4_val`

I want to fetch data from the table in the form of an array.

I have the following PHP code

```
<?php



     $select_query = "SELECT hash,l4_val FROM sdata14040";
     $list = mysql_query($select_query);
     $record = mysql_fetch_array($list);  
     $hash = $record[0];
     $data = $record[1];
     $r = array(doubleval($hash1),doubleval($data1));
     echo json_encode($r);
?>
```

The result from running the PHP file is `[1404000000,49.923]`.

In the hash column there are many values which are actually SOC with  \a time interval of  a millisecond.
I am not able to post images otherwise I would have put them on to clarify the question.
When I reload the page the result is same.
So what I want is that everytime I reload, it should respond the different answer which is related to the time on my system and the hash column with its corresponding `l4_val` value.
The hash is actually 'SOC' and this is a live database.
What should I do ?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You want to append the current time to the resulting array?

Comment: I already have that time in my hash column... and yes that time should get change in the array at every second the json_encode is returning..

Comment: How do you want to get a different result if it's **stored** in the database?

Comment: hell.... how can i  send you the snapshot of my databse... any link ??

Comment: [imgur](http://imgur.com/)?

Comment: http://imgur.com/oyqgvpa

Comment: is the database actually being updated every millisecond or what?  like will there actuslly be a new entry for you to retrieve every refresh?

Comment: The data actually is very very very large..... i have only send a part of it.. as you can see the new value of l4_val comes 20 times a second... so thats what i want to print dynamically.. for that every time my json_encode should give me a different value whenever reloaded.. hope you understood.... sorry for my english ..

Comment: yes the database is updated every millisecond..... but that data is from a older time for testing..

Comment: It's still unclear what do you want.

Comment: yes I agree I re-read twice still have no clue. what is SOC

Comment: SOC - second of century......

Comment: See..

when i fetch that data from that database by the php code i published above.. which is obviously not working well..
when i run that php file it only shows one result but what i want that whenever i run that php file at different times i should get different data... now as you see that 'hash' column actually in my database is the seconds between the today's time and time of jan 1 1970.. so actually you can say that its time of today's second...
so that hash should sense the time on my computer and match with its and send that data accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

`SELECT hash,l4_val FROM sdata14040 WHERE hash<=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY hash DESC LIMIT 0,1`

It selects the record of which the hash (which is a unix-timestamp, right?) is equal to the current unix-timestamp or as recent as possible

If you have a auto-increment primary key column it will be better to use that for the ORDER BY .. DESC clause, as it is indexed. Also, you mentioned somewhere the database is updated every milisecond so it will probably even produce more accurate results that way

Comment: Yes that is unix-timestamp...Ok wait let me try.. will return to you !!